# What object should be used in WCF (REST) to detect the current authenticated user?

Tags: wcf, rest, authentication

Should I look at Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity, OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity, or is there yet another way that I should be using?

Note that I support both Basic auth against a database, and Integrated Security if the client wants to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity is the correct one in this case.

Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity always represents the account under which your wcf thread is running.

Comment: So, what's the difference?

Comment: as I said earlier in my comment, Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity refers to the wcf worker thread's current principal (for example, if you host your WCF service in IIS, Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity would be the IIS account). ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity on the other hand contains the credentials used to authenticate the current user (caller) of the WCF service, which is what I think the OP was after

Comment: I'm not sure that Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is the account that the current thread is running under. With a test WCF self hosted REST service I wrote, the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity has the "IsAuthenticated" set to false if I'm using Basic Auth with a CustomUsernamePasswordValidator, and no value for the "Name" field. I would expect the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity to be equal to the user account under which the program was running, except in the case where you were using Kerberos and enabled impersonation.